# Using index for graph in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following code I am trying to add an index to my graph so I can label the different two lines, However I am running into the following error, how can I fix it?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-115-3c7429a6498c> in <module>()
     36     n_inv_4.append(1.0 / ((2*i)**4))
     37 n_lines = plt.loglog(n, n_inv_4)
---> 38 plt.figlegend((error_lines[0], n_lines[0]), ('Error', '1/n**4'), ('upper right'))
 39 plt.show()

TypeError: 'Text' object does not support indexing
```

and here is my code, below I have the image it outputs:

```
from math import pi, cos, sin
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def simpson(f, a, b, n):
    h = (b - a) / (2*n)
    s = f(a) + f(b)
    for i in range(1, 2*n, 2):
        s += 4 * f(a + i * h)
    for i in range(2, 2*n-1, 2):
        s += 2 * f(a + i * h)
    return s * h / 3

diffs = {}
exact = 1 - cos(pi/2)
for n in range(1, 100):
    result = simpson(lambda x: sin(x), 0.0, pi/2, n)
    diffs[2*n] = abs(exact - result)   # use 2*n or n here, your choice.

ordered = sorted(diffs.items())
x,y = zip(*ordered)
plt.autoscale()
plt.loglog(x,y)
error_lines = plt.xlabel("Intervals n")
plt.ylabel("Absolute Error")
n = []
n_inv_4 = []
for i in range(1,100):
    n.append(2*i)
    n_inv_4.append(1.0 / ((2*i)**4))
n_lines = plt.loglog(n, n_inv_4)
plt.figlegend((error_lines[0], n_lines[0]), ('Error', '1/n**4'), ('upper right')
plt.show()
```

and here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just missed the intended line for inserting `error_lines =` - it should be one line above.

However, note that you can simply add a legend without parameters (`plt.legend()`) when you set the `label`-kwargs of your plot commands before, e.g.

```
plt.loglog(x, y, label='firstplot')
plt.loglog(n, n_inv_4, label='secondplot')
```